# Request address in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621)

How do you get the address of the page you are on in JavaScript?

For example, if I had a script at `somesite.com/javascript/home.html` and I want to find out the request address (`somesite.com/javascript/home.html`), how do I get this information in JavaScript?

Comment: How was this one marked as a dupe if it was asked first?

Comment: Life just isn't fair - the duplicate duped this original into a lonely corner, stole all the reputation and then said that this one was the duplicate.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use:
    `document.location` or `window.location`

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location). Or there is a little more explanation over [there](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javalocation.html).

For clarifying matter:

**Originally Posted by Mozilla Developer Center**

> document.location was originally a
>   read-only property, although Gecko
>   browsers allow you to assign to it as
>   well. For cross-browser safety, use
>   window.location instead.

Answer (score 13):

```
window.location.href;
```

or

```
location.href;
```

`window` is the global object, so `location.href` will be identical to `window.location.href` and NOT `document.location.href` (as long as there's no enclosing function or `with` statement which shadows the property)

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that either the `window.location.href` or the `window.location.pathname` objects will have this information.Someone could confirm or deny that though.

Comment: Nope. window.location.href will return the full url including the query strings e.g http://domain.com/test.php?param=1&req=1 while window.location.pathname will return just the path e.g test.php :)

Answer (score 2):

document.URL

Answer (score 2):

```
document.location.href
```

or

```
window.location.href
```