# Get the current URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url

All I want is to get the website URL. Not the URL as taken from a link. On the page loading I need to be able to grab the full, current URL of the website and set it as a variable to do with as I please.

Answer (score 4501, accepted):

Use:

```
window.location.href
```

As noted in the comments, the line below works, but it is bugged for Firefox.

```
document.URL
```

See **[URL of type DOMString, readonly](https://web.archive.org/web/20170327080647/http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46183437)**.

Comment: In Firefox 12 the `document.URL` property doesn't update after a `window.location` to an anchor (#), while `window.location.href` does.
I didn't test any other versions of Firefox. No issues using `document.URL` were found in Chrome 20 and IE9.

Comment: also you can get host and clear location: `window.location.host` and `window.location.href.toString().split(window.location.host)[1]`

Comment: and what's `document.baseURI` about then. Basically there are 3 ways to get url `document.baseURI`, `document.URL`, & `location`.

Comment: -1: If you have a frame, image, or form with `name="URL"` then this property will be shadowed on the `document` object and your code will break. In that case, `document.URL` will refer to the DOM node instead. Better to use properties of the global object  as in `window.location.href`.

Comment: This is kind of confusing for someone looking for the rigth info (I just mean there must be an edit to show `window.location.href` instead of `document.URL` as the answer)

Comment: @aliyouhannaei you could also do `window.location.pathname` to get just the path

Comment: `window.location.pathname` //yields: "/js" (where url is "https://stacksnippets.net/js")

Comment: @AliU toString() should not be necessary as the former is a string.

Answer (score 895):

**URL Info Access**

JavaScript provides you with many methods to retrieve and change the current URL, which is displayed in the browser's address bar. All these methods use the [`Location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), which is a property of the `Window` object. You can read the current `Location` object by reading [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
var currentLocation = window.location;
```

**Basic URL Structure**

```
<protocol>//<hostname>:<port>/<pathname><search><hash>
```

- **protocol:** Specifies the protocol name be used to access the resource on the Internet. (HTTP (without SSL) or HTTPS (with SSL))
- **hostname:** Host name specifies the host that owns the resource. For example, `www.stackoverflow.com`. A server provides services using the name of the host.
- **port:** A port number used to recognize a specific process to which an Internet or other network message is to be forwarded when it arrives at a server.
- **pathname:** The path gives info about the specific resource within the host that the Web client wants to access. For example, `/index.html`.
- **search:** A query string follows the path component, and provides a string of information that the resource can utilize for some purpose (for example, as parameters for a search or as data to be processed).
- **hash:** The anchor portion of a URL, includes the hash sign (#).

With these `Location` object properties you can access all of these URL components and what they can set or return:

- **href** - the entire URL
- **protocol** - the protocol of the URL
- **host** - the hostname and port of the URL
- **hostname** - the hostname of the URL
- **port** - the port number the server uses for the URL
- **pathname** - the path name of the URL
- **search** - the query portion of the URL
- **hash** - the anchor portion of the URL
- [**origin**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin) - the `window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host`

Comment: They are not "methods" of `window.location`, but properties, and [here we have an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/406208):  `var stringPathName = window.location.pathname`.

Comment: @FabioC. You can remove it by `substring`. However, it may be useful when you want to use to redirect `document.location = "/page.html";` will redirect to root page `page.html`

Comment: Keep in mind ie9 `pathname` does not have a leading slash, so it could be `index.html`.

Comment: This answers more than just the question stated.  In fact, I searched probably around a month ago for a good way to get one or more specific parts out of the URL string (I think it was probably the current page I was trying to get), and even though other questions were more on-target, their answers were not as useful and straightforward for that purpose as this one.

Comment: One quick suggestion though: In the basic URL structure described above, there's a spot for `search`, but in the list of descriptions below, it's called a `query`. Maybe either they can be reconciled, or further explanation can be added.

Answer (score 342):

Use `window.location` for read and write access to the [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location#Location_object) associated with the current frame. If you just want to get the address as a read-only string, you may use `document.URL`, which should contain the same value as `window.location.href`.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430936/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-document-location-in-javascript/2431375#2431375

Answer (score 313):

Gets the current page URL:

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: Note that that’s the window’s location not the document’s.

Comment: It's the same thing.
Full current URL refers to the document path (external address).

Comment: Is it standardized like document.url? (I mean something like a w3c document)

Comment: `document` is the root of the document tree defined by the spec. `window` is generally equivalent but it might not be in some weird circumstances.

Comment: "`window` is generally equivalent" Nope. Never been the case. A [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is very different from a [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

Answer (score 116):

OK, getting the **full URL** of the current page is easy using pure JavaScript. For example, try this code on this page:

```
window.location.href;
// use it in the console of this page will return
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser"
```

The `window.location.href` property returns the URL of the current page.

```js
document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "The full URL of this page is:<br>" + window.location.href;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>JavaScript</h2>
  <h3>The window.location.href</h3>
  <p id="root"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Just not bad to mention these as well:

- if you need a relative path, simply use `window.location.pathname`;
- if you'd like to get the host name, you can use `window.location.hostname`;
- and if you need to get the protocol separately, use `window.location.protocol`
- also, if your page has `hash` tag, you can get it like: `window.location.hash`.

So `window.location.href` handles all in once... basically:

```
window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash === window.location.href;
    //true
```

Also using `window` is not needed if already in window scope...

So, in that case, you can use:

```
location.protocol

location.hostname

location.pathname

location.hash

location.href
```

[image: Get the current URL with JavaScript]

Comment: The only thing missing is: `window.location.port `. When possibly dealing with a port: ```window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ":" + window.location.port : '') + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash === window.location.href```

Comment: Your answer is missing `window.location.search` as `window.location.href` also provide query params.

Answer (score 53):

Open **Developer Tools**, type in the following in the **console** and press **Enter**.

```
window.location
```

Ex: Below is the screenshot of the result on the current page.

[image]

Answer (score 47):

**To get the path, you can use:**

```js
console.log('document.location', document.location.href);
console.log('location.pathname',  window.location.pathname); // Returns path only
console.log('location.href', window.location.href); // Returns full URL
```

Answer (score 32):

Use: `window.location.href`.

As noted above, `document.URL` **doesn't update** when updating `window.location`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.URL).

Answer (score 28):

**To get the path, you can use:**

```
http://www.example.com:8082/index.php#tab2?foo=789

Property                    Result
------------------------------------------
window.location.host        www.example.com:8082
window.location.hostname    www.example.com
window.location.port        8082
window.location.protocol    http:
window.location.pathname    index.php
window.location.href        http://www.example.com:8082/index.php#tab2
window.location.hash        #tab2
window.location.search      ?foo=789
window.location.origin      https://example.com
```

[image]

Answer (score 25):

- Use `window.location.href` to get the complete URL.
- Use `window.location.pathname` to get URL leaving the host.

Comment: window.location.pathname does not include query and hash fragment

Answer (score 21):

You can [get the current URL location with a hash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser) by using:

**JavaScript:**

```
// Using href
var URL = window.location.href;

// Using path
var URL = window.location.pathname;
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

Comment: Don't use `URL` as your variable name; there is already a constructor on window.URL. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Answer (score 20):

For complete URL with query strings:

```
document.location.toString()
```

For host URL:

```
window.location
```

Answer (score 20):

```js
// http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/page/2?name=jake&age=34
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
/*
hash: ""

host: "127.0.0.1:8000"

hostname: "127.0.0.1"

href: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/page/2?username=jake&age=34"

origin: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"

password: ""

pathname: "/projects/page/2"

port: "8000"

protocol: "http:"

search: "?name=jake&age=34"

username: ""
*/

url.searchParams.get('name')
// jake

url.searchParams.get('age')
// 34

url.searchParams.get('gender')
// null
```

Answer (score 14):

window.location:

```
 Location {href: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript",
 ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList,
 origin: "https://stackoverflow.com",
 replace: ƒ, assign: ƒ, …}
```

document.location:

```
  Location {href: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript", 
ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList,
 origin: "https://stackoverflow.com",
 replace: ƒ, assign: ƒ
, …}
```

window.location.pathname:

```
"/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript"
```

window.location.href:

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript"
```

location.hostname:

```
"stackoverflow.com"
```

Answer (score 11):

```
var currentPageUrlIs = "";
if (typeof this.href != "undefined") {
       currentPageUrlIs = this.href.toString().toLowerCase(); 
}else{ 
       currentPageUrlIs = document.location.toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Nikhil Agrawal's answer is great, just adding a little example here you can do in the console to see the different components in action:

[image]

If you want the base URL without path or query parameter (for example to do AJAX requests against to work on both development/staging AND production servers), `window.location.origin` is best as it keeps the protocol as well as optional port (in Django development, you sometimes have a non-standard port which breaks it if you just use hostname etc.)

Answer (score 9):

For those who want an actual URL object, potentially for a utility which takes URLs as an argument:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: The other great thing about this method is that you can use it as a URL builder- add or remove params, change the path, etc. and then use the .toString() method to always get a perfectly valid, nicely formatted URL string!

Answer (score 7):

You have multiple ways to do this.

1:

```
location.href;
```

2:

```
document.URL;
```

3:

```
document.documentURI;
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply use this:

`document.URL`

or this:

`window.location.href`

Answer (score 6):

```
location.origin+location.pathname+location.search+location.hash;
```

and

```
location.href
```

does the same.

Answer (score 5):

The way to get the current location object is `window.location`.

Compare this to `document.location`, which originally only returned the current URL as a string. Probably to avoid confusion, `document.location` was replaced with `document.URL`.

And, all modern browsers map `document.location` to `window.location`.

In reality, for cross-browser safety, you should use `window.location` rather than `document.location`.

Answer (score 5):

In jstl we can access the current URL path using `pageContext.request.contextPath`. If you want to do an Ajax call, use the following URL.

```
url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/controller/path"
```

Example: For the page `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36577223` this will give `http://stackoverflow.com/controller/path`.

Answer (score 4):

## Short

```
location+''
```

```js
let url = location+'';

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the full link of the current page through `location.href`
and to get the link of the current controller, use:

```
location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are referring to a specific link that has an **id** this code can help you.

```
$(".disapprove").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/sample/page/"+id+"')?>",
        type: "post",
        success:function()
        {
            alert("The Request has been Disapproved");
            window.location.replace("http://localhost/sample/page/"+id+"");
        }
    });
});
```

I am using ajax here to submit an id and redirect the page using **window.location.replace**. just add an attribute `id=""` as stated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check for page is loaded completely in

```
browser,window.location.toString();

window.location.href
```

then call a function which takes url, URL variable and prints on console,

```
$(window).load(function(){
   var url = window.location.href.toString();
   var URL = document.URL;
   var wayThreeUsingJQuery = $(location).attr('href');
   console.log(url);
   console.log(URL);
   console.log(wayThreeUsingJQuery );
});
```