# How to get current page path in jQuery (while doing ajax call)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am doing Ajax call using jQuery and my URL is like

http://localhost;3327/DummyAps/Demo.aspx

In Demo.aspx page i have a WebMethod, which i wanted to call. While doing jQuery ajax call i am giving the URL as "/DemoWebMethod", where "DemoWebMethod" is the Webmethod present in Demo.aspx page.

But while calling the WebMethod it is calling the URL 
http://localhost;3327/DummyAps/DemoWebMethod but i want to call
http://localhost;3327/DummyAps/Demo.aspx/DemoWebMethod.

I know that changing the URL from "/DemoWebMethod" to "Demo.aspx/DemoWebMethod" will solve the problem but can i do it without writing that (because i have some problem with that).

Can someone please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current URL with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery as well

Comment: But if my url is like Demo.aspx#divNote or something like this then it is not working.
In this case i have to get the whole URL and find out the exact page name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it, in case you want the entire url:

```
window.location.href.split("#")[0]
```

For just the path, try this:

```
window.location.pathname
```

Comment: This also might work if you're passing a get variable:
window.location.href.split("?")[0]