# Reusable jQuery delete function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I using the following function to delete a row in a table

```
//delete individual row
jQuery('.stdtable img.delete').click(function(){
    var c = confirm('Continue delete?');
    if(c) jQuery(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

This code is in a separate js file and is common to all pages.
Now I would like to add an Ajax action that deletes the row from the database. But depending on which page I'm on, it must call different controller.

Example:
Product page must call delete in ProductController
ProductGroup page must call delete in ProductGroupController

How to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'depending on which side you're on'?

Comment: `side` ... typo for `site`? and did you actually mean `page` or so?

Comment: [see this SO item](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3512201/474535). retrieve your controllers path and assemble an ajax call with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need some method of defining which controller to call, you could put a `data` attribute on the table. Something like this:

```
<table class="stdtable" data-remove-url="@Url.Action("DeleteRow", "MyController")">
    <tr data-id="1">
        AAA
        <img class="delete" src="foo.jpg" />
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2">
        BBB
        <img class="delete" src="foo.jpg" />
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Then in your jQuery you can get this value as the `url` parameter of your request, along with the `id` to delete.

```
jQuery('.stdtable img.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Continue delete?')) {
        var $el = $(this);
        var $tr = $el.closest('tr');
        var url = $el.closest('table').data('remove-url');
        var id = $tr.data('id');

        $tr.fadeOut(function() { 
            $el.remove();
            $.post(url, { rowId = id }); // do the delete on the server 
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom attribute to your table or row with contains the url off the controller you need to call.  In your method you can read this custom attribute to get the url of your controller.Look here for the [JQuery attr methode](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to click the image with class delete to make a call to delete that row in the database. The simplest solution would be

```
<img data-rowid="1" src="something.jpg"/>
```

```
jQuery('.stdtable img.delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var c = confirm('Continue delete?');
    var that = this;
    if(c) {
        var id = this.data("rowid");
        jQuery.ajax({ url : "/resource/"+id, method : "DELETE" 
              statusCode: {
                 200: function() {
                       jQuery(that).parents('tr').fadeOut(function(){ 
                            jQuery(that).remove();
                       });
                 }
              }});

    }
    return false;
});
```