# Can I get the referrer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a badge for my website.

**UPDATE and CHANGE the question body**

I'm trying to send the URL of the page that contain my badge back to my site when someone clicks the badge.

Comment: Maybe its just me, but I really don't understand the question. If you are asking how to find the URL of the current page, that question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript

Comment: @Greg I edited it to what I *think* the OP is asking. Please let me know if you think I am wrong. Cheers.

Comment: @alex: sorry for my bad language. i think the question body is good ;). my title was wrong. and for the answer is the document.url is enough?

Comment: @alex, at this point it is anyone's guess :-). @raika, you really need to write a more clear explanation of what you're trying to achieve. What will the badge do?

Comment: @Raika If you want the current page URL, use `document.URL`. If you want the referrer, use `document.referrer`.

Comment: @Greg :  its something like [stack flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair). but i want the source url that contain my badge. like www.thatdomain.com. and sorry for my bad question :|

Comment: @Raika, it isn't so much the language. It is that you are saying so little about what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to send the URL of this page back to your own page when someone clicks the badge? I ask because you mention the querystring below.

Comment: @Greg : yes and i want to do it with querystring. is it wrong? and what should i do?

Comment: @Raika, it isn't reasonable to expect folks on here to pull the details out of you point by point. I suggest you write a detailed description of what you want to do in the question body.

Comment: @Greg : ok. but do me a favor and edit title yourself. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the referrer with `document.referrer`, but bear in mind this may not be set. Proxies often send a different one or strip it, and I don't think you can check `X_FORWARDED_FOR` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
alert(document.URL);
</script>
```

Mozilla Dev Center is really good and complete -- a great resource. You can find it  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document#Properties).

Comment: is it safe too add it to my querystring?

Comment: `Returns a string containing the URL of the current document.` Is that really what he wants? I admit the title is confusing...

Comment: @alex : yours better so i change title :P

Comment: @Raika My edit overwrited yours 9 seconds later. Still, from the question body, it seems the referrer is really what the OP wants.

Comment: @alex, I suppose you're right! Saw what I wanted to see... ;) @Raika, you should mark @alex's answer as correct.