# document.URL vs location.href > no results

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, location

I am working on a Firefox extension. For this I need the current URL. I tried both possibilities with the following result:

```
location.href   >  chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
document.URL    >  undefined
```

They are called in the event if a menu button is clicked. Why is it not working?

Comment: Similar question here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript

Comment: @lashleigh: The OP knows already about these methods. The problem is that the context is different. Maybe it is a duplicate, but not of the question you linked to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are accessing Firefox's DOM, not the web page's one.

To get the `window` element for the current web page, you can use [`window.content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content).

So you can get the location via `window.content.location.href`.

Comment: Or window.content.document.URL, either way