# Javascript for extracting only the domain and top level domain from a URL String

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript function that can extract only the 'domain' and 'top-level domain' from a url string.

The current questions on StackOverFlow do not resolve the answer for non-urls too.

> Examples:
>
> 1. https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl -> google.com
> 2. yahoo.com/mail -> yahoo.com
> 3. http://helloworld.net/index/test/help -> helloworld.net
> 4. www.stackoverflow.com/ -> stackoverflow.com
> 5. invalid.url -> "return false or an empty string"

Any/All help is welcome and appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Unless wanting this for learning purposes, there is already something that will do that: [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), though it does need to have the protocol part for it to be valid input, and  will have to strip the subdomain parts (www) to get the output you seek

Comment: using the `window.location` as the parameter for the URL method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get top level domain (base domain) from the url in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449340/how-to-get-top-level-domain-base-domain-from-the-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

A regex can suit your needs, for example:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:[^/]+\.)?([^./]+\.[^./]+).*$
```

[See on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RCrAHS2yj1NuYGKI)

In JS:

```js
function extractDomain(url) {
  return url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^\/]+\.)?([^.\/]+\.[^.\/]+).*$/, "$1");
}
```

If you want to handle TLDs that contain dots (like `.co.uk`), then I'm afraid the only solution is to hardcode them, for example:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:[^/]+\.)?([^./]+\.(?:co\.uk|com|de|es|fr)).*$
```

[See on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NgCgfZwRfND9PW-p)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple.

window.location.href variable stores the current url of the website.

With this variable, you can get the top domain.

```
var url = window.location.href
var split1 = url.split('//')[1];   // Get the string except the protocol.
var split2 = split1.split('/')[0];    // Get the domain url.
// Get top domain url.
var domain = split2;
if (split2.substring(0, 4) == 'www.')
    domain = split2.slice(4)
```

variable `domain` is the value you want.

Comment: This will fail for `https://accounts.google.com` or even `https://foo.bar.foo.bar`.

Comment: In that case, the top domain will be "accounts.google.com". I think. And it will work like that.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the code. When getting split2 variable, variable split1 must be used but I used url (my mistake.)