# JS : get top domain

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'am looking for a way to get the top-level domain from a website. For ex.

- From [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) => return `google.com`
- From subsite.site.com => return `site.com`
- From subsite.site.co.uk => return `site.co.uk`

As a basis, I can use `document.domain` or `location.hostname` but its doesn't get the top-level domain. I need it in order to build a cookie that would be stable on the whole domain.

The best we found today:

```
      var t = document.domain.split(".");
      if (t.length > 2) {
        domain_name = t.slice(1).join(".");
      }
```

i.a. if a domain has more than 2 parts, remove the first part. It seems quite OK but I am not that confident.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.origin` 
The origin read-only property of the Location interface is a USVString containing the Unicode serialization of the origin of the represented URL.
`location.host`
Is a USVString containing the host, that is the hostname, a ':', and the port of the URL.
`location.hostname`
Is a USVString containing the domain of the URL.

read : [Location - Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#wikiArticle)

```js
console.log(window.location.origin);
console.log( window.location.host );
console.log( window.location.hostname );
```

Comment: None of those are what the OP is looking for.

Comment: i found this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449340/how-to-get-base-domain-from-the-url-in-javascript`

Comment: There is no accepted answer here, doesn't look like they found a reliable solution