# How to send current URL using ajax without rediretion?

Tags: php, ajax

I need a help to send current page url to my database or to email without page redirection ..!Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send it through an AJAX request, taking the URL from `window.location` or `document.URL`.

With jQuery, this would be as simple as

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.com/report.php',
  data: 'url=' + window.location.toString()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See this for getting the current URL: [Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

Once you have the URL you should be able to just send it via AJAX.

Comment: freedompeace's post gives this to you. I wasn't sure if you were using jQuery, ExtJS or plain JavaScript nor did I know what your PHP page would accept (POST? GET? What format? etc) so I didn't add any code as I didn't know if it would add value or not to my answer.