# How to get the current browser URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a website on a host `example.myhost.com`
but I also have a sub-domain for French `fr.example.myhost.com` which is different than example.myhost.com.

If I'm at `fr.example.myhost.com` and I use `window.location.href`, I get `example.myhost.com` instead of `fr.example.myhost.com`.

How do I get the URL typed in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: Do you see the right content if you run `alert(location)`?

Comment: `location.href` should give you the entire url.

Comment: @Douglas, no , the alert box gives example.myhost.com

Comment: @AlienWebguy, it doesn't give me the current url

Comment: @Alon what browser are you using?

Comment: In firefox, it works, i just test it right now with a modification of my /etc/hosts file. What browser have you at the moment ?

Comment: Perhaps your page is using frames/iframes so the URL of your window is not the same as shows in the browser?

Comment: Maybe your host is doing some server redirect - contact them to check this up.

Comment: @jfriend00, I think there is some frames or redirection, not sure

Comment: try using document.getElementsByTagName('iframe') and see if you get a result. also, is this a site we can view to test out for ourselves?

Comment: @LordZardeck , I have noticed that on firefox its working ok, but on chrome it shows something different, without the fr.

Comment: @Alon I have tested it in chrome, and it works for me. is this site something we can view to try different options? don't need access, just need to load the page that has this problem. It may just be your browser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`window.location`

The subdomain shouldn't make a difference.  If, however, you've typed the URL in the address bar, after the page has loaded (but not hit enter), then that's a different story altogether.

Comment: true, but the way he worded the question i'm assuming he actually has loaded the page with that url

Comment: In my browser window, I see fr.example.myhost.com while when I do window.location, I see example.myhost.com

Comment: do you have an actual webpage example?

Answer (score 3):

That's weird, cause it works for me. You might try:

- window.location.host
- window.location.hostname
- window.location.origin

Answer (score 2):

Look the same question here : [Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

Use :

```
console.log(document.URL);
```