# ExtJS: get current URL in ExtJS style

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Title says it all: how do I get the current URL using ExtJS?

There are already answers about fetching the URL using [`document.URL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript) and [`window.location.pathname`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery). However, since I'm using [`Ext.Object.fromQueryString`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-fromQueryString) in the same script, I'm looking for a similar ExtJS method that returns the current URL.

I'm on ExtJS `4.1.3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there isn't something like this in ExtJS, and if there was a function like that, under the hoodcap they'd also do a `window.location`

Comment: Is `window.location` entirely cross-browser?

Comment: Yes it is, unless you're talking about really old browsers, but then you can't even use ExtJS so, all the browsers ExtJS supports have `window.location`

Answer (score 1):

Using Extjs getWin method, location url can be fetched. There is no direct function to get the url.

```
Ext.getWin().dom.location.href
```