# Get the URL including fragment using PHP or JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url

My website URL is something like the below:

```
http://localhost/naveendalmeida/news.php#news_6
```

How can I get the URL to include #news_6 using PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=get+url+hash+php+javascript

Comment: @YourCommonSense To be fair, none of those results (that I saw) directly answer the question.

Comment: And who is voting to close "not a real question"? To me the question is crystal clear, just *very* basic. This could be the top Google result within a couple weeks and then you can close others as "duplicate".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current URL with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.href` should return what you need (javascript).

Getting it in php seems a little more verbose:-

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/get-current-page-url.html

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  alert(window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: This only returns the hash..

Answer (score -3):

For php parse_url function is utilized for parsing url

For retrieving fragment part of url  through  parse_url function

e.g

$url_info=parse_url($url);

echo $url_info['fragment'];

Comment: That doesnt return the url of the current page..