# Set "active" accordion menu after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm trying to set accordion menu "active" after click on link and change the page...

```
<div class="menu">
        <dl>
            <dt><a href="index.asp">HOME</a></dt>
            <dt><a href="#" class="submenu">QUEM SOMOS</a></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="empresa.asp">EMPRESA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="institucional.asp">INSTITUCIONAL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="nossos_produtos.asp">NOSSOS PRODUTOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="responsabilidade_social.asp">RESPONSABILIDADE SOCIAL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="responsabilidade_ambiental.asp">RESPONSABILIDADE AMBIENTAL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <dt><a href="#" class="submenu">PRODUTOS</a></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul class="produtos">
                        <%do while not rscat.EOF%> 
                        <li><a href="produtos_categoria.asp?categoria=<%= rscat("categoria")%>"><%= rscat("categoria")%></a></li>
                        <%  rscat.MoveNext
                        if rscat.EOF then Exit do %>
                        <% Loop %> 
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <dt><a href="informativo.asp">INFORMATIVO</a></dt>
            <dt class="no_border"><a href="contato.asp">CONTATO</a></dt>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('dd').hide();
        $('dt a.submenu').click(function(){
            $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

i'm trying too, use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681033/accordion-menu-active-state-after-link-click but dont work...

what i try (but don't work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('dd').hide();

            var sPath = window.location.pathname;
            var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            $("dt a.submenu[href='" + sPage + "']").parents("dd:visible").show();


            $('dt a.submenu').click(function(){
                $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");

                var checkElement = $(this).next();
                if ((checkElement.is("dd")) && (checkElement.is(":visible"))) {
                    return false;
                }
                if ((checkElement.is("dd")) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                    $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");
                    checkElement.slideDown("normal");
                    return false;
                }

            });


        });
    </script>
```

Well, the first sublinks `ul` point to especific pages, but the another sublink `ul class=produtos` show the categories that's on database, and uses same link on each categories like: `produtos_categoria.asp?categoria=xxxxxx`...

If the user, click on "EMPRESA", on the page `empresa.asp` the `QUEM SOMOS` menu need to be opened. And if the user click on some categories under the menu `PRODUTOS`, on the page `produtos_caegoria.asp` the `PRODUTOS` need to be opened..

I'm clear?

So.. what i need to do?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Qf7Js/1/

Comment: please post the generated html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qf7Js/1/

Comment: I should have emphasized on the _generated_ word. The HTML was already there but it contains some mix of, may be server-side language code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qf7Js/2/

Comment: I am a bit confused.  Is your issue here with the accordion, or with the page that loads when a link is pressed?

Comment: with the accordion.. I need the menu to be "open" when you click on any sublink... if you click on sublink that's inside `QUEM SOMOS` this need to be opened. And if click on any categories inside the `PRODUTOS` this must be opened too, including the next page that opens

Comment: _if you click on sublink that's inside QUEM SOMOS this need to be opened. And if click on any categories inside the PRODUTOS this must be opened **too**_ . Are you aiming for a tree control? like the yellow part in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/TreeWeb/TreeWeb.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf7Js/3/) to see if it does what you require. As far as I could understand the problem, you want to, on page load, automatically open the accordion menu that contains the current link. 
This can be achieved with following code

```
//say this is the current link which can be retrieved in real website using window.location object
var init_link = 'institucional.asp'

//then instead of hiding all <dd>, using $('dd').hide(), you only hide the ones that don't contain an <a> that has href equal to init_link.
$('dd').filter(function () {
    return $('a[href="' + init_link + '"]', $(this)).length == 0
}).hide();
```

Just change the `init_link` value to what the current URL. Watch out for the hostname part because your `<a>` might not contain absolute URL. This might help [Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript).

To get currnet URL without the hostname part, you *could* (not *must*) use following code

```
var init_link = window.location.href.replace(window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/', '')
```

Comment: If I manually set the value of the variable, this is running ... but if I using the automatic script this don't working...

Comment: the site is at the following address: `www.example.com/test/index.asp` ok.. so.. i'm using some alert to show the variable content, and this is storing the following address: `teste/index.asp`

Comment: using this `var sPath = window.location.pathname;<br/>
            var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);` I got get the address correctly.. but. on links with `produtos_categoria.asp?categoria=something` this don't work...

Comment: I'll check in a bit and update my answer about getting the right URL :)

Comment: i make another questionm, if you like post on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337875/active-accordeon-menu-dont-work-with-sublinks-with-query-strings

Comment: BTW, if it works with `var sPath = window.location.pathname;` then it should work on URLs having query string with `var sPath = window.location.pathname+window.location.search;`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, it seems like all you are looking to do is apply a class to the `dt` in addition to hiding/showing the next `dd` item? This can be achieved with callback functions, or by simply chaining the method on. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $menu = $('dl.menu');
    $('dd', $menu).hide();
    $('dt a.submenu', $menu).on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $parent = $(this).parent('dt');
        if($parent.hasClass('active')){
          $parent.removeClass('active').next('dd').slideUp("slow");
        } else {
          $parent.siblings('.active').removeClass('active').siblings("dd").slideUp("slow", function(){
            $parent.addClass('active').next('dd').slideDown("slow");
          });
        }
        $("dd:visible", $menu).slideUp("slow", function(){
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps provide some direction.