# Active Accordeon Menu don't work with sublinks with query strings

Tags: javascript, accordion

@Ejay Help me to set "opened" the main link if i click iin some sublinks of this...

here: [Set "active" accordion menu after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325178/set-active-accordion-menu-after-click?answertab=active#tab-top)

i make some modifications like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var sPath = window.location.pathname;
            var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            var url = sPage.split('?')[0];

            $('dd').filter(function () {
               return $('a[href="' + url + '"]', $(this)).length == 0
            }).hide();

            $('dt a.submenu').click(function () {
               $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
               $(this).parent().next('dd').slideDown("slow");
               return false;
            });

        });
</script>
```

This script only works if my link is

```
<a href="test.asp">TESTE</a>
```

if my link is that way: `<a href="test.asp?category=BLABLABLA">BLABLABLA</a>` this don't work..

what is wrong

Can see the menu working partly here: http://alsite.com.br/saks_div/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
```

works for URL's like `abc.asp` then following should work with URL's having a query string, e.g., `produtos_categoria.asp?categoria=something`

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname+window.location.search;
```

Comment: @Preston this doesn't work ATM because `sPath` holds `/saks_div/institucional.asp` but the href of your `<a>` is only `institucional.asp`. Let me come up with a better code that takes into account all possibilities :)

Comment: but i'm using `sPage` to call.. `sPage` holds only `institucional.asp`..BTW... i'm waiting you.. look at the page i've provide... i'm show `alert()` width values of `sPage` and `url`