# How to access the current page url typed in jsp?

Tags: java, .htaccess, jsp, servlets, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I use **.htaccess** file for url rewritting.To enable .htaccess file I  put the **urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar** file inside WEB-INF\lib\ and inside web.xml I have added the following code.

```
   <filter>
      <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
```

defaults to false. use mod_rewrite style configuration file (if this is true and confPath is not specified confPath will be set to /WEB-INF/.htaccess)

```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>modRewriteConf</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping>`
```

My .htacces file code is

```
    RewriteRule ^/()$ index.jsp [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^/login/?$ login.jsp [NC,L] #Handle requests for "login"
    RewriteRule ^/logout/?$ login.jsp [NC,L] #Handle requests for "login"
    RewriteRule ^/contact_us/?$ contact.jsp [NC,L] #Handle requests for "contactus"
    RewriteRule ^([/A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ user.jsp [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([/A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$ user.jsp [NC,L]
```

I have one user.jsp file. I used regular expression for url maping so that what ever i type in url it open the user.jsp file.
I want to access the actual url typed inside the user.jsp file.
Suppose I type `http://localhost:8080/project/abhiramgiri`. I used

```
  <%
       String getURL=request.getRequestURI();
       out.print(getURL);
  %>
```

It shows the path to the file as `http://localhost:8080/project/user.jsp`
Actually I need `http://localhost:8080/project/abhiramgiri`.
It does not show the actual typed url. It retrieve the original path.
Please, Help me for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it the URL that shows the web browser? depending on your application you could use JavaScript to get the URL  using document.URL (see [get-current-url-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript) )
You must regard security.