# How can I get everything after the forward slash in my url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I visit my url, my script will get the current URL and store it in a variable with

```
var currentURL = (document.URL);
```

I'd like to get everything after the forward slash in my url because there will be a hash ID after the forward slash like this:

```
www.mysite.com/XdAs2
```

so this is what would be stored in my variable currentURL and I'd like to take only the `XdAs2` from it and store that into another variable. In addition, I'd like to know two other things.

1. Is document.URL the best way to get the current URL or will I have issues with some browsers?
2. If I were to try to open that URL using an iframe, will document.URL still work? or must there be an address bar present containing the url? I would really appreciate answers for those questions three questions. Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for this Regex:- /(\/\/[^\/]+)?\/.*/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some pseudo code:

```
var currentURL = (document.URL); // returns http://myplace.com/abcd
var part = currentURL.split("/")[1];
alert(part); // alerts abcd
```

Basically:

1) `document.URL` should work fine in all major browsers. For more info refer to this [Mozilla Developer Network article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL) or this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

2) for an `iframe`, you need to write something like: `document.getElementById("iframe_ID").src.toString()`

Comment: Thank you, what is Pseudo code and can you answer these questions I have too: Is document.URL the best way to get the current URL or will I have issues with some browsers?

If I were to try to open that URL using an iframe, will document.URL still work? or must there be an address bar present containing the url? I would really appreciate answers for those questions three questions. Thank you

Comment: Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean if I open a page in iframe, if the page contains the "Pseudo code" above, will it get the url? for example <iframe src="http://www.mysite.com/XdAs2"></iframe> will the script contained in the page loaded by that iframe be able to get the url from that iframe src so I can then split it and get the hash id after the forward slash XdAs2?

Comment: Nope, it will not get URL in that case.

Comment: Do you know a way to get the URL in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, you can do he following in order to access every inch of the current URL:
`www.mysite.com/XdAs2?x=123`

assuming you have the following url: 
1- get the url in a jQuery object

`var currentUrl = $(location)`

2- access everything using the following syntax

`var result = currentUrl.attr('YOUR_DESIRED_PROPERTY');`

some common properties:

- hostname => `www.mysite.com`
- pathname => `XdAs2`
- search => `?x=123`

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thank you Mohammed, If I were to try to open that URL using an iframe, will document.URL still work? or must there be an address bar present containing the url?

Comment: If I add a username to that url www.mysite.com/Brandon/XdAs2 can I using pathname will I get Brandon and XdAs22 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything after the host, use `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Mohammed's answer you can do the same thing in vanilla javascript:

```
var urlPath = location.pathname,
    urlHost = location.hostname;
```