# Get POST value to Url

Tags: java, javascript, android, post

I am working on an API. When I make request to API I have to send a url, on which the API will return success / falier message with POST method. 
**So my question is how I can read this value that have been POST to url?** 
**Should I have to create custom url and set intent filter or is there any other alternate**
In my application is based on HTML and JavaScript.

**Edit**
The API is ccavenue a payment gateway. For making payment I have submit form data as described in API reference using HTML and JavaSacript. After payment (success/falier) it to Redirect Url sent in request. Now the problem is response which I am unable to get. How I can get this response.

Comment: What is your server side script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript

Comment: @gelleby It just show current url but I need values that have been posted to url

Comment: $_REQUEST in php code

Comment: @ChinnuR server size script is JSP

Comment: Down voter please answer the question first

Comment: I'm a little confused buddy! are you talking about reading the post parameters at client size(using javascript) or server side?
at the server side(if the form is not `multipart`) you would access the parameters by `request` field(using `getParameter("paramName")` method).