# How to find domain of current request in Shopify liquid?

Tags: shopify

I have a store with multiple custom domains. I'm trying to find what domain is currently being requested.

**Domains:**

> somestore.myshopify.com
>   store.customdomain1.com
>   store.customdomain2.com

When a request comes into store.customdomain1.com/collections is there a variable that will tell me it's from store.customdomain1.com ?

Answer (score 10):

It looks like Shopify added a new Request object recently.  I can't find much documentation, just the one example - but it looks like it addresses your need.  Use `{{ request.host }}` to get the current actually-requested domain.

Reference: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/request#request-host

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible with liquid. There is `{{ shop.url }}`, but it appears to output your store's Primary Domain (Admin > Settings > Domains) rather than the actual domain the user requested.

I think you'd have to use Javascript instead. Either `document.URL` or `window.location.href` will give you what you want. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript).

Comment: I have the same question. There is also a {{shop.domain}} variable, and I'd expected it to display the current domain, but it seems to return the same value as {{shop.url}} :(.