# Set javascript variable based on dynamic url

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, dynamic-url

Does anybody know a javascript code that will detect the dynamic url of the page (?q=Chicken) and setup a javascript variable called 'query'. I would then like to display the variable as text.

This will all be onload.
Can this also be done with a textbox? (Input type text - set text to query)

I cannot use php of asp. Just html and javascript!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: `window.location.search`

Comment: Seen that but could not get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

Once you have the full URL, you should be able to parse it using regexs or other any other method that you can think of.  Then, you could just set the text of an html element to that query.  Or you could create a whole new element and append it somewhere

Comment: Way too complicated for me. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parameters with

```
document.location.search
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex can get pretty messy. Check out this Stackoverflow answer instead:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

(it links to http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/ which suggests using this snippet of code:)

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
  }
  return(false);
}
```

Usage:

Given this url: http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1&image=awesome.jpg

Calling `getQueryVariable("id")` - would return "1".
Calling `getQueryVariable("image")` - would return "awesome.jpg".

Comment: So I write something like this?      document.write(getQueryVariable("id"));