# How Link Wordpress Image Files from js

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I am developing a site into sub dirctory-

sitename.com/subdirectory/

I am including an image link from my theme js file.(js/custom.js)

sitename.com/subdirectory/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/333.png

But when i move the site to main directory. I want the sitename.com/subdirectory/ will automatically converted to http://sitename.com/

is that possible? I try to used

/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/333.png

but its not working.

Comment: try with URL redirecting. For your Reference http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

Answer (score 0):

you should do js code in your php script before including script file.

```
var image1= '<?php echo content_url();?>/uploads/2014/05/333.png';
```

Then use this variable `image1` in your js file. 
This will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually i am using that image for a google map marker. But its not working.                                                               var LocsA = [
 {
   lat: 40.71465,
   lon: -74.03573,
   title: 'Greene St',
   html: [
                    '<h3>DHS at 70 Greene</h3>',
       '<p>70 Greene St Jersey City</p>',
     '<p>NJ 07302</p>'
   ].join(''),
   icon:'image1'
 },

Comment: you should use `var LocsA = [ { lat: 40.71465, lon: -74.03573, title: 'Greene St', html: [ '<h3>DHS at 70 Greene</h3>', '<p>70 Greene St Jersey City</p>', '<p>NJ 07302</p>' ].join(''), icon:image1 },` image1 without quotes.

Comment: yes, i used icon:image1 but it's not working. any idea?

Comment: Can you see `var image1= '<?php echo content_url();?>/uploads/2014/05/333.png';` in your source code? is it before your included file?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current URL by javascript from this [Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

Then check if current URL in subdirectory or not then you can decide what link should to pass to your image link in javascript file