# AngularJS $location get path before hash

Tags: angularjs

I need to extract the path before the # in my AngularJS app, so for example if my app url is:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/app/#/home
```

I need to get only this portion:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/app/
```

I've tried using $location.path, $location.abspath but couldn't find any function that can get me the first portion before the #. Can someone please help me by telling me what I am missing here? and if there is a way to get the first portion of the url (before the #)? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript

Comment: @MattWay I am trying to get it using AngularJS $location

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could split the path into the pathname and hash parts, and then use the pathname only:

```
$location.absUrl().split('#')[0]
// "http://www.example.com/folder/app/"
```

`split` is just a Javascript string operation returning an array:

```
'http://www.example.com/folder/app/#/home'.split('#')
["http://www.example.com/folder/app/", "/home"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but using $location.path().split('#')[0] it returns the second portion of the url, that after the #, in other words /home am I missing something here? Thanks

Comment: Worked with $location.abspath().split('#')[0] thanks

Comment: @MChan - `$location.path().split('#')[0]` does not work because it only returns the portion of the url *after* the hash. So split is just returning a single-element array containing the original string -- i.e. the path (because the hash character was not found).

Comment: Looks like there's a typo, It should be `$location.absUrl().split('#')[0]` instead.