# using jQuery to get url and extract url segments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

On a webpage that has a list of categories, and each category title is linked in this format: `http://localhost/admin/category/unpublish/2`

I wrote the following js code, trying to capture the url and the segments 'unpublish' (action) and '2' (id), and need to send the request to `http://localhost/admin/category`

```js
$('#statusChanges a').click(function(evt) { // use the click event of hyperlinks
  evt.preventDefault();
  var url = $(location).attr('href');
  // var action = url.segment(3);  /*JS console complains that url.segment() method undefined! */
  // var id = url.segment(4);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $(location).attr('href'),
    dat: '',
    /* do I need to fill the data with json data: {"action": "unpublish, "id": 2 } ? but I don't know how to get the segments */
    success: function(data) {
      $('.statusSuccess').text('success!');
    },
    error: function(data) {
      $('.statusSuccess').text('error!');
    }
  });
}); // end of status change
```

Comment: This question might be useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-javascript/16602140#16602140

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
var url = $(location).attr('href').split("/").splice(0, 5).join("/");
```

**Update Answer:**

User `this` object to get current anchor link see below

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Comment: I found $(location).attr('href') gives me the current url, but I would like to get the url on the <a href></a> tag. thanks

Comment: @TonyGW , try `this` for current url `$(this).attr("href")`;

Comment: all right, so this gives me the right url on the hyerlink: var url = $(this).attr('href'); thanks for help!

Comment: @TonyGW `this` is refer to current target... you have attached event on `<a>` tag so `this` provides you current `<a>` element reference.

Comment: $(this).attr('href') I got undefined on firefox 37

Answer (score 9):

Split the URL into segments first:

```
var segments = url.split( '/' );
var action = segments[3];
var id = segments[4];
```

Comment: This is simple, but note that it should be `var segments = window.location.href.split( '/' );`. See: [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1034642/3416774)

Comment: This was assuming url is already defined, i.e. var url = $(location).attr('href');

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Then you can have an array to work with from which you can get the action and id.