# How to get url params while bootstrapping angular app

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app that I am manually bootstrap so I can get config data from the server before the app starts up. The problem is I need an id param from the url to pass to the server in order to get the config data.

Is there a way to use angular to harvest some url params while I bootstrap the app? I need a param for the $http.get url.

```
fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication);

function fetchData() {
    var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
    var $http = initInjector.get("$http");

    return $http.get("/path/to/data.json").then(function (response) {
        angular.module('app').constant("config", response.data);
    }, function (errorResponse) {
        // Handle error case
    });
}

function bootstrapApplication() {

    // manually bootstrap the app
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var reportingApp = document.getElementById('ClaimSummaryApp');
        angular.bootstrap(reportingApp, ['app']);

    });


}
```

Comment: You can just get the url with `document.URL` - then pull whatever you need out of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser

Comment: pass it as a variable in script tag