# How to get the current page URL using Javascript and using it in a <a href="[the_URL]">

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that I want to insert in it some social buttons so users can share it on twitter and facebook. 
I want to get the page URL and insert it in in the share buttons.

How do I get the current page URL and use it in a `<a href="">` tag or inside other parts on my HTML code?

I know about `document.URL` on javascript. I just don't know how to apply it on an  tag.

Comment: `var URL = document.url`

Comment: The solution is so easy to find. Did you even try searching?

Comment: Reference http://jsfiddle.net/e96cdktd/

Comment: @planet260 I did. Didn't find anything like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current url in web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser)

Comment: AND USE IT IN A HREF!

Comment: ^ I googled. you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("myLink").href = document.URL;
```

```html
<a id="myLink" href="">Click me I am a link</a>
```

Hover your mouse over the link to see which link.