# Is there any way to get ONLY the PHP page of the current page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, url, location, filenames

I want to get the my exact location (only PHP page) using javascript, I'm currently using `window.location` to get the exact url for example: `localhost/empc/myfolder/functions.php` what is the code if I want to get only `functions.php` as a result? Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: You can see this already given answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser that will help you.

Comment: [Here's](http://phpjs.org/functions/basename/) a JS implementation of PHP's basename function. It'll get what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use location object to do this, To remove the "/" before the file name you can use substring method.

```
 location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this pretty simple

```
 var url = 'localhost/empc/myfolder/functions.php';

 var url = url.split('/');

 alert(url.pop());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Use the javascript [split function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to separate the string into pieces and then access the last element to get the file name:

```
var str = "localhost/empc/myfolder/functions.php";
var arr = str.split("/");
alert(arr[arr.length-1]); //this will alert functions.php
```