# Get value form url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have the following URL:

http://www.mywebsite.co.id/?bannerid=1234

What I need is to get the value of "bannerid" from the URL into a variable and then use it in a Javascript.
Does anyone know how to grab that value using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to access it as part of the `<head>` tags, I don't know, and then loop through it as a string to look for your keyword and grab the value after it.

You could use:

`window.location.href` to get your URL.

to get the URL, and then use a `for` loop to iterate through the string until you come to a *b* followed by an *a*, etc..., then grab the numbers after that.

[Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser)

You might be able to do this by checking the first nine characters for a match, then move one character over and check for a match, etc... until you get to `bannerid=`, which would show true, and then you can cut the string there and grab the numbers.

I hope that was clear enough, let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: can you help me with the code?

Comment: Can you help me? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Yes. Give me a sec and I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that.