# Dynamically changing a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is  a URL (wrapped in  a-tag) in my html page. How  can I send some additional data (it is can be change **dynamically** by a client (inputs)) to the server when my user  making a GET-request (for example, as parameters of the URL).
I can't use html-form, I just should do it as URL.

I try to explain clearer.
URL is just a link to the content. However my server need some additional data for child action. It were entered by user  (some entry fileds - for example a string of the search)

Comment: Can you please post the html code for that `<a>`?

Comment: consider just using a `<form>` with the `[action]` attribute, then no JS is necessary.

Comment: "I can't use html-form" — Why not? The use case you describe is exactly what forms are designed for.

Comment: Looks like a job for URL with parameters. `mod_rewrite` can convert to it from a "normal" URL but the current formulations don't show an immediate need for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some like that:

### HTML:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' id='myLink' data-url='http://www.google.com/' />
```

### JS:

```
var src = $('#myLink')[0].getAttribute('data-url');
$('#myLink')[0].href = src + "?myNewParameter=myValue";
```

I hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

This will use ajax to call your server on mydomain.com, and a php script called server.php. It will pass a single parameter called url, and it will equal whatever is in the address bar.

If successful, and if the server responds with anything, it will be written to the console log

```
$.ajax( {   
    "data": "/server.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href.toString()) ,
    "success": function(data)
             {   console.log(data); }
});
```

Extra info on getting the URL: [Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser)