# p5.js: How can I make my sketch load a different .txt file depending on the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, installation, processing, p5.js

Apologies if this question isn't worded very clearly. I'm working on a text-analysis visualisation and I have multiple HTML pages loading the same Processing sketch with p5.js. The only difference between the pages is that I need the sketch to load a different .txt file in setup() or preload() depending on what HTML page it is. The rest of the sketch remains identical.

How can I make my sketch load a different file (01.txt, 02.txt etc) depending on what page it's in? (book_one.html, book_two.html etc). Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write JavaScript in p5.js, so the first thing I'd google is "JavaScript get current url" to see how to do that.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser) is the first result for that search, and it says you can get it like this:

```
window.location.href
```

Now you just have to write p5.js code that uses this JavaScript variable. Maybe something like this:

```
function setup(){
    if(window.location.href == "http://example.com"){
       //load 01.txt
    }
    else{
       //loat 02.txt
    }
}
```