# Need base url inside javascript tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, base-url

I am trying to use the base url of my php page inside javascript tags but I don't know javascript very well. I use baseUrl;?> in PHP but that doesn't work in javascript.  Can anyone tell me what I can use to replace baseUrl;?> below?

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        BobbieEDITOR.replace("plados", {
               contentsCss: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>data/css/bltry.css"
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Is the content on the same server?

Comment: what's wrong with what is shown? what does it produce in browser source?

Comment: That should work in php, assuming php is loading the page.  If the page is `.html` then no it wont work.  Because, well we use the `.php` extension for well php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, use Referenced pages (below) to fine tune it:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var baseUrl = window.location.host;
        BobbieEDITOR.replace("plados", baseUrl + '/data/css/bltry.css');
    };
</script>
```

References:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

[Get current URL in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser)

http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery