# Fill form field from querystring using javascript/

Tags: javascript, forms

I have search for an answer to this and not come up with any answers. I can't post what I have so far because I stuck where to start.

I am trying to populate the email field of a form using Just javascript and a query string. The thing is, the page with the form only allows me to add javascript to the header or footer, I cannot access any other part of the page.

The field does have an ID, which is simply "email".

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you access other parts of the page?  Is the "center" of the page an `<iframe>` on another domain or something?

Comment: Can you please give us the code to check?

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser) to get the url and split it to get the querystring.

Comment: I can't access other parts of the page because it is a hosted form.  It is an Infusionsoft order form and I need to prefill the email field.

Comment: Then you are likely using an `<iframe>`.  Look at this: [The iframe cross-domain policy problem](http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/)