# Current Page URL in a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, I am hard coding the url.

```
<a class="button_link" href="https://somewebsite.com/submit/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsomecrazyurl.com" target="_blank" aria-label="Sharei">
```

Instead I want something like this:

```
<a class="button_link" href="https://somewebsite.com/submit/?url=returnpageurl()" target="_blank" aria-label="Sharei">
```

Edit: For the record I used

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

However nothing gets returned.

Is there any  **cross-browser Javascript** to return the current url of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a browser compatibility solution use

```
window.location.href
```

where `document.URL` is having issues with Firefox with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1034642/3464552)

```
<a class="button__link" href="#" target="_blank" aria-label="Sharei" id="current_url">Current URL</a>
```

This is simple to use as below with no complexity ,the thing what I found is you are not assigning any value to the `href` attribute and by default in jquery it assigns back

> https://somewebsite.com/submit/?url=returnpageurl()

Now the below one should work for your case,

```
 $("#current_url").attr("href",window.location.href );
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the path, you can use:

```
  var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
  var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
```

You can use jQuery's attribute selector for that.

```
var linksToGoogle = $('a[href="http://google.com"]');
```

Alternatively, if you're interested in rather links starting with a   certain URL, use the attribute-starts-with selector:

```
var allLinks = $('a[href^="http://google.com"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve by using the `window.location.href` JavaScript window property.

Html Example:

```
<a href="https://somepage.com" id="link1">my link</a>
```

Javascript

```
var a = document.getElementById('link1');
a.href = a.href + '?returnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#link1').attr('href', $('#link1').attr('href') + '?returnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
```

Note the use of the built in function `encodeURIComponent(str)` [reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

> The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a Uniform Resource
>   Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain
>   characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing
>   the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape
>   sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).