# How to get path before # in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In IIS, my web app runs in an application under the website. So instead of being accessible at `www.example.com`, it is actually at `www.example.com/somepath/`.

If I use `window.location.pathname`, I can get my hands on the `/somepath/` portion, but with Angular's `$location.path()` I get nothing. From the official documentation, it seems like `$location.path()` should only get whatever comes after the hash, e.g. `www.example.com/somepath/#/nextbit` will give me `/nextbit`.

So how do I get my hands on the actual path where the website is hosted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current URL in web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser)

Comment: `absUrl` is what you need.

Comment: @Ryan No, this is different. I'm not looking for the full URL (then absUrl would be the full answer). This is specifically about getting the path of the site, not the page. In my example, the aim is to get `/somepath/` whereas location.href will give the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to do it using Angular `$location` service, try this:

```
var baseUrl = $location.absUrl().replace('#/' + $location.url(), '');
```

`absUrl()` will get the whole URL, while `url()` will get the part of the url after `#/`

Answer (score 0):

Since the information coming before the hash is not considered superbly relevant to Angular's internal workings, I don't think bypassing Angular's internal method (`$location`) would be a bad practice in this case.

I would go with your original assumption, since it will still work:

```
location.pathname
```

Unless you're worried about the bindings inside of Angular having fired prior to getting that path (which shouldn't have an affect on a static, IIS application path), this should be fine.

Comment: It's better to use $location if you ever intend to write any tests.