# Don't show part of website depend on url

Tags: jquery, html

I had 2 websites www.example-with-prices.com  and www.example-without-prices.com.

Both sites are basically the same, except one doesn't show the prices of the products and it's a lot of trouble to maintain both sites.

Now I rebuild these websites and want to have just one website and place the price information in `<div>` what is shown just if you use www.example-with-price.com.
I try to use something like this, but I can not find a way to hide if the user go to my site using www.example-without-prices.com

```
<div id='hideshow' data-value="price1" style="display:none">    
<table>  price table here </table> 
 </div>

<script>
    $('[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {
      var dataValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
      dataValue = $('#'+dataValue);
      $(dataValue).toggle('hide');
    });
**  <!-- add something what toggle hide if user enters site via www.example-without-prices.com -->


</script>
```

Comment: You ca check what is the current URL. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1034642/2159528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution in another post which i want to share.

```
<script>
    if(window.location.href == 'www.example-without-prices.com')
        {
            $('#price1').hide();
        } else {
            $('#price1').show();
        }       
</script>



<div id='price1'>  
       <!--- price table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added by default to hide - Then show if not a no price host

```
<style>#hideshow{display:none}</style>
<div id='hideshow' data-value="price1" style="display:none">    
<table>  price table here </table> 
 </div>

<script>
    $('[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {
      var dataValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
      dataValue = $('#'+dataValue);
      $(dataValue).toggle('hide');
    });
**  <!-- add something what toggle hide if user enters site via www.example-without-prices.com -->

if (window.location.hostname !== 'www.example-without-prices.com') {
    $('#hideshow').show();
}

</script>
```

Comment: thank for giving this solution, however I didn't got it worked. I've made with the suggestions an other solution, which i've posted here too.

Answer (score 1):

I can use something like this:

```
if(window.location.href == 'www.example-without-prices.com'){
    //your code
}
```