# How to Insert a PHP Value into an Input Value

Tags: php, jquery, input

I have a form on a page that is generated dynamically.

One of the fields is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pageURL" id="pageURL" value="" />
```

I'd like to on page load set that value with the current browsers url using:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I can't simply put that php into `value=""` because that field is generated dynamically. But is there simply javascript or jQuery to load the current page url in the users browser (parameters and all) into a value of an input on a page?

Comment: How are you appending the `input` to the DOM? Assuming PHP code is available for use at that point then you can `echo` the `value` as you normally would.

Comment: You just want the URL in an input field? I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser would answer that. Then set it, `$('#pageURL').val(...)`.

Comment: This should work: `<input type="hidden" name="pageURL" id="pageURL" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?" />`

Comment: How is the field generated dynamically? Is it generated by PHP or is it added to the DOM by JavaScript after the page has loaded?

Comment: Unfortunately, while simply echoing in value would be quite easy under normal stances, this question would be on doing it remotely since that input is generated dynamically by a plugin that for reasons beyond this text box can't edit directly. However I see a one line solution below that solves it. Thank you for everyone sharing your thoughts. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery to add the url to your input field

```
$('#pageURL' ).val(window.location.href);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1k7eghj/

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for, something very short, clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to retrieve the URL parameters using JavaScript. If not please tell me I will turn this as a comment.

Here is the function you need:

```
function getSearchQuery() {
    // Checking if there is any parameter in the URI.
    if (document.location.search) {
        // Returning the parameters of the URI as an object.
        return document.location.search.substr(1).split("&").reduce((item, part) => {
            part            = part.split("=");
            item[part[0]]   = part[1];
            return item;
        }, {});
    } else {
        // Returning an empty object.
        return {};
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. You just need to change the input value with this function.

Comment: No I wasnt asking for javascript code. I was asking for make custom post types in a way that the slug is not added to the url.