# Keep selected item on pageload

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a selectbox to set the total records per page with following JS:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#itemspage').on('change', function () {
          var items = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (items) { // require a URL
              window.location = "afhaal_pagination.php?limit="+items; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

This is working, no problem. Now I want to have the selected value is selected when the page reloads with that value.

Any help please..

Comment: you need to do that part on backend and send value to the frontend. because when the page reloads you lose the data on that page. can you give us some backend code?

Comment: you can also use `$_SESSION`

Comment: parse window.location.href after page reloaded

Comment: see more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser

Comment: You could also set a cookie , so that the option remains even if user moved to other page and came back