# unable to fetch data after redirecting to next page

Tags: angularjs

I am redirecting to edit page after clicking on edit button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"  ng-click="editData(n.id.userId)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
```

On click on this button following code is working.

```
$scope.editData = function (data, $window) {
     console.log(data);
     window.location = 'update-data?id=' + data;
}
```

Now I am redirected to `www/xxx/update-data?id=1` url.
From there I want to fetch user data for id=1 and want to show at page.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the Url using `$window` and do one of the following based on your requirement

```js
var url = "www/xxx/update-data?id=1";
var id = url.substring(url.indexOf('=')+1);
console.log(id);
var url = "www/xxx/update-data?id=1";
var id = url.substring(url.indexOf('?')+1);
console.log(id);
```

But the best option (angular way of doing things) will be to do routing and use `$routeParams` or `$stateparams` based on your router.

**Relevant Links**:

1. [Configure Routes and Views using $routeProvider](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)
2. [Documentation ngRoute](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/)
3. [UI-Router for AngularJS (1.x)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)
4. [Get Current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: I an doing as above is correct or i have to use ng route

Comment: If you don't have that many routing, I guess above method will be fine. But if your application so many pages, then it is better to use routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the url and get id and write code to get the data for the corresponding id inside ngOninit ()