# Running backbone app on different URLs

Tags: backbone.js, sitecore, single-page-application, backbone-routing

Is it possible for the backbone router to recognize that the URL it is running on is different?

I need the behavior of the app to change before the hash-bangs.

/members#login

vs

/members/benefits#about (Need the app to behave differently here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm not asking about backbone being able to detect routes before the hashbang. Not how to get the window.location.href.

Comment: Backbone is a JS lib, use JS to get whatever you want in the URL and go from there. There's nothing specific about Backbone here. You could check [`pushState`](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) is that fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control behavior of the app depending on the url that is not part of hash, you should use [`pushState`](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start). Otherwise backbone router only deals with the part after hash. In that case you can implement the logic yourself.