# Can I make custom url for using particular event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I make custom url for using particular event in javascript?
For ex. index website has following code and if I type domain.com/menu the website will load with nav-open?

```
    var navTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-toggle-click-area')[0],
        body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    navTrigger.addEventListener('click', toggleNavigation);

    function toggleNavigation(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        body.classList.toggle('nav-open');
    }
```

Comment: To answer your question, yes you can.

Comment: You'll have to [analyze the `window.location`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript) and conditionally open the navigation based on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
if (path.length) {
  var page = path[0];
}
```

This will store the word `menu` from your example above into the `page` variable.