# loading custom font on a specific URL

Tags: performance, css, font-face, webfonts

I have few custom font faces (for english) defined in my css, i also have other font faces that only needs on specific language pages. How do i load these language fonts only on language pages.

example: `www.abc.cn` or `www.abc.jp` needs to load language fonts to user, but when user enters `www.abc.com` it only loads english font to improve my page's performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [getting the current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript) and add conditions according to the domain's extension. e.g:

```js
var url = window.location.href;
console.log("Current URL: " + url);

if(url.includes(".com"))
  console.log("Load English fonts");
else if(url.includes(".cn"))
  console.log("Load Chinese fonts");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have specific CSS for specific sites/languages: not only loading one or other custom font but also using them for headings, text, etc: `font-family: the-one-for-japanese,sans-serif;` and `font-family: the-one-for-chinese,sans-serif;` for example.

I'd compile them as _partials in different CSS with an automated tool like Gulp or Grunt and Sass, PostCSS or LESS
or at least load 1 specific CSS for each site and then 1 common to all of them (`@font-face` at-rules should appear as soon as possible so loading begins soon but then other specific rules are at risk of being overridden by common ones).
You can also write @font-face in your HTML markup in a style element, then your common CSS and finally a second specific one if it exists.

OT: Specific CSS to each language may or may not be written in your generic CSS depending on the specific declarations you need.

- set relevant lang attribute on html element `<html lang="fr-qc">` (french in Quebec, Canada but `<html lang="fr"` – french whether in France, Belgium, Swiss, Togo, Senegal, Quebec, French Polynesia, wherever – is fine too).
- In CSS, you'll multiple rules like `[lang|="fr"] .yourclass { font-family: "with-diacritics", sans-serif; background: url(images/fr/bg.jpg); }` (with ja, zh, en, it, nl, dk, etc)

It doesn't *really* add weight to your CSS because it'll compress especially well. It's more CSS to be parsed by the browser which isn't a real problem because it's fast (I mean you've a lot of more important things to optimize before that like images, JS or… your fonts) but it is barely more bytes to be transferred because Gzip on the server! :)