# How to get current url in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I can't explain myself in title. What i want is get string between slashes. Like that: 
**www.example.com/foo/bar/id/1**
i want to get **"foo"**. Because i made these codes.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
            if(window.location.href = "news/" + ui.item.slug){
           window.location.href =null;
            }
            else
                window.location.href ="news/" + ui.item.slug;
        }
```

I have a autocomplete search field. When i clicked a result, its redirecting me to **www.example.com/news/34523**
In this page if i use search field again, it redirects me to **www.example.com/news/news/12412** After that i got 404. But if i am not in news tab, for example **www.example.com/foo** its working perfecly when i use search field. I just need an if statement, if i am in news pages act like another page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: Do what you're doing, then use REGEX to strip out the part you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use the `location.pathname` property to get the part between the first and second slash and run code based on this.

```js
console.log(window.location.pathname);
console.log(window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] === "foo");
```

To show that this works, here is another snippet, acting as if `url` was `window.location`:

```js
let url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = "http://www.example.com/foo/bar/id/1";

console.log(url.pathname);
console.log(url.pathname.split("/")[1] === "foo");
```

Comment: Sure, nice to have helped you. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your url that gets redirected. Try the below code.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
            if(window.location.href = "/news/" + ui.item.slug){

            }
            else
                window.location.href ="/news/" + ui.item.slug;
        }
```