# How to get the url of the BrowserWindow?

Tags: javascript, electron

This is a pretty basic question. In electron, how do I check the url/filename of a BrowserWindow?

```
let win;

app.on('ready', () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow();

    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'main.html'));

    win.on('closed', () => {
        app.quit();
    })
});
```

Ok, so say, this is the code, say after a certain event happens in a different (add:insert) BrowserWindow, I want to get the url from the main BrowserWindow (win).

```
let addWin;

ipcMain.on('createAddWin', ()=>{

    addWin = new BrowserWindow();

    addWin.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'add.html'));

    addWin.on('closed', () => {
        addWin = null
    });

ipcMain.on('add:insert', (e,insertObject) => {
//some event happens
//retrieve url from main window (win)
});

});
```

How do I go about this, I prefer to not have to send an event to the win to then send the url through ipcRenderer, though this is definitely possible.

Comment: Please provide some code to illustrate what you've tried?

Comment: `window.location.href`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: Guys, note that this is about reading from the electron BrowserWindow object, not a plain html page. Not a duplicate of that question at all.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Getting the window's URL is possible by using the [getURL()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsgeturl) instance method of the window's [webContents](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winwebcontents) instance property:

```
let currentURL = win.webContents.getURL();
```