# How can I get the active URL from an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I have an Electron app which kind of wraps a web URL and renders it. During the course of user action the user traverses through this app to different page. I would like to see if the user is on the default page or any other page. I tried using [`BrowserWindow.webContents.getURL()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsgeturl) as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185293/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-browserwindow/54187857#54187857) but it doesn't return the correct URL. Is there any way I can track the active page which the user is seeing through this Electron app?

Comment: You say that you don't get the correct URL. That can be anything. What output exactly are you getting? We need some more information to be able to help you. Please [edit] the question to include further details.

Comment: I always get the intial URL .SO for example if i opeen google.com I always get the same