# I want access address bar content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to route to a dynamic page in JavaScript,

Is there any way I can do this,

localhost/page.html/001

Can I write a code like,

```
If (url last characters == 001) {
   //Do something
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var lastUrl = window.location;
lastUrl = lastUrl.replace("localhost/page.html/", "");
if(lastUrl == "001"){
    alert(lastUrl);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
const currentUrl = window.location.href
```

To get the current URL of the side (In this case `localhost/page.html/001`), then:

```
const filterUrl = currentURL.split("/");
if (filterUrl[2] === '001') { /* Do stuff */ } else { /* Do other stuff */ }
```

If your URL's are going to be always like that you could use this little snippet to filter them.