# How to redirect site's port only when changing site more **details in topic**

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to be able to redirect site's port only since I'm running the website as 3 different types of IPS. So on WebServer hosting device I've edited the host file `127.0.0.1` to `q`. So on host device I can access my website as `q:8080`. On internal devices I can access it as `192.168.43.1:8080` and I've port forwarded version.I have DNS and changed the external port. So other people can access my site by entering `http://ladasno.hopto.org:8080`. So the reason I'm asking this because I pretty lack knowledge yet. So I want for each address to be redirected from `8080` to `9090` (For Internal ports) and from `80` to `90` for external ports. So what should I do.

So I've tried like looking for a way to read website's url user is accessing from (FAILED TO FIND). Then I've tried to like to make window.location.replace("urls") 4 times at once. Then I used .. since I thought it will autofind the part that has left of the url

So first I just tried:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location.replace("http://q:9090/Page/Index.html");
    window.location.replace("http://192.168.43.1:9090/Page/Index.html");
    window.location.replace("http://ladasno.hopto.org:9090/Page/Index.html");
   }
```

This has failed since redirects to last URL I've provided. Then I've tried:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location.replace("..:9090/Page/Index.html");
   }
```

And this just shows error in console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replace' on 'Location': '..:9090/Page/Index.html' is not a valid URL.
    at redirect (http://192.168.43.1:8080/:5:21)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://192.168.43.1:8080/:10:31)
```

Please HELP ME!

So I have high expectations for stackoverflow community members. And I don't think I can describe actual results because I haven't seen any details.

Comment: in general, redirection of this kind (i.e. just changing the port number for all requests) is something better done in your web server config (e.g. in a htaccess file, for Apache servers) rather than in application code.

Comment: P.S. "read website's url user is accessing from (FAILED TO FIND)" ...hmm. What did you search for?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript is the most obvious resource, but there are hundreds of places you can get the answer. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp is also quite useful. (I googled "javascript get current url", for your info).