# How to prefill automatically form field with current page url

Tags: javascript

This is the field that I want to get prefilled by the current page's url

```
<input type="url" class="form-control" name="inv" id="inv" placeholder="Referrer's Link" size="100"  />
```

Anyone with any idea please show me how

I am aware of the javascript code

```
document.getElementById('inv').value = window.location.href;
```

The problem is that I dont understand how to implement it

Comment: `document.getElementById('inv').value = window.location.href;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: @RyanWilson that doesnt answer my question!

Comment: Now how do I implement that to prefil the url field??

Comment: You need to add the value to the input after the dom has loaded, there is a `DOMContentLoaded` event you can subscribe to in your javascript file then use the line above. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: but why not do it with php? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First dont use type="url", its down supported by IE,
via php get all url data from $_SERVER and you can concat what ever you want.

```
<?php
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

?>
<input value="<?php echo $actual_link?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="inv" id="inv" placeholder="Referrer's Link"   />
```

Comment: Don't use something because a decade-old browser with minimal usage doesn't support it? https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url

Comment: Perfect! You are amazing.. I've really been looking for this. Thank you