# How do I get URL in angular?

Tags: angular, url, routes

I need to make my hamburger button be an hamburger or a cross depending on the url. So I need to get my current url.

This is what I have right now:

When I click the hamburger button, the view switches to the settings view (like intended) and my url changes to "http://localhost:4200/settings", but when I try to get the url it returns just a '/'.

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

public href: string = "";

  constructor(private router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.href = this.router.url;
        console.log(this.router.url);
  }

}
```

**##########EDIT#############**

The answer by Alvaro worked but it refreshes the page (I haven't thought about it before, sorry). And I just want it to change view and not refresh the page.

What I have right now is:

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="hamburguer">
        <a (click)="getUrl(); showFirst=!showFirst;">
            <img *ngIf="!showFirst" src="assets/images/hamburguer.png" id="hamburguer">
            <img *ngIf="showFirst" src="assets/images/cross.png" id="hamburguer">
        </a>
</div>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private _location: Location) { }

  getUrl(){

    if(window.location.pathname != "/settings"){
        window.location.pathname = "/settings";
    }else{
        this._location.back();
    }

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here's a video: https://vimeo.com/342053009

Comment: Did you try adding `router.url` inside the constructor and log it?

Comment: It is because you are assigning url only on `ngOnInit` and it does not change unless you reconstruct `HeaderComponent`. You need to subscribe route changes. @Alvaro's answer should help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get it with pure javascript:
`window.location.pathname`

Or use the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) and also subscribe to its URL events. Here is an example:

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

   activatedRoute.url.subscribe(url => {
       // do what you need here
   }
}
```

And to import the `ActivatedRoute` add the following line:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: ty! i used the ````window.loaction.pahtname```` and it worked. the only problem is that it refreshes the page (i haven't thought about this before, sorry), and I just want it to change the view. I edited my post so you can see what i have right now

Comment: To change the view, have you tried with `this.router.navigate(['../new-package'], {relativeTo:this.activatedRoute});` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
 import { Location } from "@angular/common";

 url: string;
 constructor(location: Location) {
    this.url = location.path();
 }
```