# Javascript: Alert() if js matches specific URL

Tags: javascript

So I am developing a Quizizz cheat script that runs on plain JS it works, but the only problem is that I don't want it to be executed unless it matches the URL https://quizizz.com/join/game/ and if possible display an alert "Valid Game Found".

If you need the code I would post it but only if necessary, not because I don't want to share but I don't want to get hate if you get banned

Comment: "If you need the code I would post it but only if necessary, not because I don't want to share but I don't want to get hate if you get banned" ?? Welcome to SO! Please [post any relevant code you have](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - it's the main way we can assist. Also have you checked out [this question to get the current URL in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the window.location.href like so

```
if(window.location.href === 'https://quizizz.com/join/game/'){
   alert('Valid game found')
}
```