# Need help adding and removing .active class based on page URL using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add .active class to `<a>` tag depending on which page I'm currently on, so I can style it.

When I go to Home page, this should happen:
 `<li><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a></li>`
`<li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>`

`<li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>`

When I go to About page, then this should happen:
 `<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>`
`<li><a class="active" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>`

`<li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>`
Etcetra...

This image describes what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

```js
const currentLocation = location.href;

const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');

const menuLength = menuItem.length

for (let i = 0; i<menuLength; i++){
if(menuitem[i].href === currentLocation){

menuItem[i].className = "active"
}
}
```

```css
ul li a {

color: black;
background-color: silver;
}

ul li a.active {

color: white;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
   <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="http://example.com/home/">HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://example.com/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://example.com/location/">LOCATION</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

It just doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `href` of every link is just `#` while `window.location` contains the full address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target only the `.navbar-links a` then loop over each one, in the loop do 2 things:

- Check if current `hash` or `path` equals the links `href` attribute.
- Add an event handler to the link to set the class, and before setting it, loop over the others to remove the current (not needed if you're not using a hash).

```js
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-links a');

menuItem.forEach(el => {
  // current
  if (el.getAttribute('href') === (location.hash || '#home')) {
    el.classList.add("active")
  }

  // handle click
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    // remove others
    menuItem.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"))
    // set active
    e.target.classList.add("active")
  })
})
```

```css
ul li a {
  color: black;
  background-color: silver;
}

ul li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#location">LOCATION</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If not using a hash the extra steps are not needed as it will reload the page:

```js
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-links a');

menuItem.forEach(el => {
  if (el.getAttribute('href') === (location.path || '/home')) {
    el.classList.add("active")
  }
})
```

```css
ul li a {
  color: black;
  background-color: silver;
}

ul li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/home">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="/location">LOCATION</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Okay, first JS you posted works perfectly UNTIL new page loads(refreshes). I've made a quick video on youtube to show you what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3uFtVgaHU4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: you simply need to match what's in href. whats in the href for each link, hash, path, full url or a mix of both?

Comment: I actually forgot to meantion that I use only 1 header instance for all pages(I don't have seperate header instances for each page). Here is the code and that I used in the video: https://codepen.io/pen/ZEOgyNN

Comment: I've mentioned it in the answer.. `location.path` is for `/foobar/baz` whilst `location.hash` is for `/#foo-bar` links, you have to use the correct one for it to match the if statement to apply the active class. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript (you could use just window.location instead of location.path or location.href) using query params like in your pen would need `location.search` not `location.hash`

Comment: Got it to work with `location.href` . Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

location.href will return the full url.

I think what you want is location.pathname, so if you have something like [www.yourdomain.com/home](http://www.yourdomain.com/home) location.pathname would be equals to "/home" while location.href would be equals to [www.yourdomain.com/home](http://www.yourdomain.com/home).

Also, all a tags are pointing to the same '#'.

What you want to do is probably set the href to the path you want.

for ex:

```
<li><a href="/home">HOME</a></li>
```

Comment: I excluded real links on purpose, I edited my post to re-add them to avoid confusion, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript you can use:

```
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
menuItem.forEach( item => {
    if(item.href===location.href){
    item.classList.add('active')
    return;
  }
})
```

I used foreach array method to loop through all links. In the if statement, we are confirming if item.href (href attribute of a tag) is equal to current url you are on, if that is true, it will add class of active to that link and return.

Not sure if that's what u wanted i am also a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```js
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-links a');

menuItem.forEach(el => {
  // current
  if (el.getAttribute('href') === (location.href || 'http://example.com/home/')) {
    el.classList.add("active")
  }

  // handle click
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    // remove others
    menuItem.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"))
    // set active
    e.target.classList.add("active")
  })
})
```

```css
.navbar-links a {
  color: black;
  background-color: silver;
}

.navbar-links a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/home/">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/location/">LOCATION</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help