# Copy active browser's url to clipboard with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write a function so I can copy the current browser's url to the clipboard when clicking on a link. I am still trying to understand this code, at this point I don't know how to create an input, set its value to the URL of the current document, select its contents and execute copy, as I understand it is the way to hack it. Right now when clicking on the text I get an error: Cannot read property 'select' of null... Any cue would be appreciated.

```
export function Copy() {
    const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState("")
    const textAreaRef = useRef(null)

    function copyToClip(e) {
        //navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.target.getAttribute("href"))
        textAreaRef.current.select()
        document.execCommand("copy")
        setCopySuccess("Copied")
    }

    return (
        <>
            {document.queryCommandSupported("copy") && (
                <Text onClick={copyToClip}>
                    Copy
                </Text>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is really composed of two:

1. [How to get the current URL in js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034621/7884305)

```js
const url = location.href;
```

2. [How to copy text to clipboard using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript):

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
```

Finally:

```js
export function Copy() {
    const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState("")
    const textAreaRef = useRef(null)

    async function copyToClip() {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(location.href);
        setCopySuccess("Copied");
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Text onClick={copyToClip}>
                Copy
            </Text>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function test(){
  let urlField = document.createElement('urlField')
    urlField.innerText = "your link here"
    document.body.appendChild(urlField)
    urlField.select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    urlField.remove()
}
```

It will create another field to save any text you want and copy it to clipboard, after that it will disappear.

In your code `const textAreaRef = useRef(null)` textAreaRef  has reference to not exist component so it cannot select or append text

Comment: `document.execCommand()` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) and should no longer be used. Use the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) instead

Comment: Thanks for that, I will update and use it!

Answer (score 0):

```
const textareaEl = document.createElement('textarea');
textareaEl.value = window.location.href;
document.body.appendChild(textareaEl);
textareaEl.focus();
textareaEl.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
document.body.removeChild(textareaEl);
```

In Case you are copying the current URL to the clipboard, you can use the above codes (the number one code), and the following is for the time you are defining a handle click just by adding (number 2 code):

```
const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);
function copyTask() { const el = document.createElement('input');
    el.value = window.location.href;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select(); document.execCommand('copy'); 
    document.body.removeChild(el); setCopied(true);
} 
<Button onClick={copyTask}> {!copied ? 'Copy link' : 'Copied!'} </Button>
```

Comment: In Case you are copying the current URL to the clipboard, you can use the above codes (the number one code), and the following is for the time you are defining a handle click just by adding (number 2 code):

Comment: const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

   function copyTask() {
    const el = document.createElement('input');
    el.value = window.location.href;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
    setCopied(true);
  }

<Button onClick={copyTask}>
          {!copied ? 'Copy link' : 'Copied!'}
        </Button>