# React component - output of the url where the component was used

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know that I have basically no clue whatsoever.

So I am using a react form component on our website which is used on hundreds of different urls (blogs and so on). What I want to achieve is, that the url, where the form was submitted from (e.g. test.com/blog1 or test.com/blog2) is put out by the form so I can receive it with my http request and play it out in Microsoft Teams or whereever. It is likely "window.location.href" - but how do I get it as an output correctly?

My component looks like this:

```html
import React, {useState} from "react"
import {FaPhone} from "react-icons/fa";
import {Link} from "gatsby";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}


const EasyForm = ({
                    title = "Kostenfreie Erstberatung",
                    subtitle,
                    butttonText = "Jetzt absenden"
                  }) => {
  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm();
  const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = async (f) => {
    setDisabled(true);
    const url = `/.netlify/functions/newsletter-form?logAll=true&debug=true`;
    try {
      f.source = "Form";
      const result = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(f)
      });
      var formSection = document.getElementById("formsection");
      var buttonSection = document.getElementById("buttonsection");
      var thankSection = document.getElementById("thanksection");
      var errorSection = document.getElementById("errorsection");
      if (result.status === 200) {
        formSection.style.display = "none";
        buttonSection.style.display = "none";
        thankSection.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        formSection.style.display = "none";
        buttonSection.style.display = "none";
        errorSection.style.display = "block";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      formSection.style.display = "none";
      errorSection.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={"m-3 my-20 relative z-20"} key={"mykey"}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} method="POST">
        <div className="shadow-lg sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden border-t border-gray-100">
          <div className="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-2 sm:p-6">
            <div className="relative">
              <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center" aria-hidden="true">
                <div className="w-full border-t border-green"/>
              </div>
              <div className="relative flex justify-center">
                <span
                  id="schadenheadline"
                  className="px-2 bg-green-lightest text-3xl font-bold text-gray-600">
                  {title}
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id={"formsection"}>
              <div className="mb-4 font-semibold pt-3 text-gray-500 text-lg">
                {subtitle}
              </div>
              <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
                <div className={"col-start-1"}>
                  <label htmlFor="lastname" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    Name*
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-1">
                    <input
                      {...register("lastname", {
                        required: true,
                        minLength: {
                          value: 2,
                        }
                      })}
                      type="text"
                      className={classNames(errors.lastname ?
                          "border-red-500 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500" :
                          "border-gray-300 focus:ring-green focus:border-green",
                        "block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm " +
                        "border-gray-300 rounded-md")}
                    />
                    <span
                      className="text-sm text-red-500">{errors.lastname && "Name muss mindestens 2 Zeichen lang sein"}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label htmlFor="firstname" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    Vorname*
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-1">
                    <input
                      {...register("firstname", {
                        required: true,
                        minLength: {
                          value: 2,
                        }
                      })}
                      type="text"
                      className={classNames(errors.email ?
                          "border-red-500 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500" :
                          "border-gray-300 focus:ring-green focus:border-green",
                        "block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm " +
                        "border-gray-300 rounded-md")}
                    />
                    <span
                      className="text-sm text-red-500">{errors.firstname && "Vorname muss mindestens 2 Zeichen lang sein"}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={"col-start-1"}>
                  <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    E-Mail*
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-1">
                    <input
                      {...register("email", {
                        required: true,
                        pattern: {
                          value: /\S+@\S+\.\S+/,
                        }
                      })}
                      type="email"
                      autoComplete="email"
                      className={classNames(errors.email ?
                          "border-red-500 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500" :
                          "border-gray-300 focus:ring-green focus:border-green",
                        "block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm " +
                        "border-gray-300 rounded-md")}
                    />
                    <span
                      className="text-sm text-red-500">{errors.email && "Bitte gültige E-Mail eingeben"}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label htmlFor="phone" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    Telefon
                  </label>
                  <div className="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
                    <div
                      className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                      <FaPhone className={"h-8 w-8 text-gray-400 pr-4"}/>
                    </div>
                    <input
                      {...register("phone", {
                        required: false,
                        minLength: {
                          value: 8,
                        }
                      })}
                      type="text"
                      autoComplete="tel"
                      className={classNames(errors.phone ?
                          "border-red-500 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500" :
                          "border-gray-300 focus:ring-green focus:border-green",
                        "pl-9 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm " +
                        "border-gray-300 rounded-md")}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <span
                    className="text-sm text-red-500">{errors.phone && "Telefonnr. muss mindestens 8 Zeichen lang sein"}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={"col-start-1"}>
                  <div>
                    <label htmlFor="fin" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      FIN
                    </label>
                    <div className="mt-1">
                      <input
                        {...register("fin", {
                          required: false,
                        })}
                        type="text"
                        placeholder={"Feld E im Kfz-Schein"}
                        className={classNames(errors.fin ?
                            "border-red-500 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500" :
                            "border-gray-300 focus:ring-green focus:border-green",
                          "block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm " +
                          "border-gray-300 rounded-md")}
                        aria-describedby="email-description"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <fieldset className="space-y-3 mt-4">
                <div className="relative flex items-start">
                  <div className="flex items-center h-5">
                    <input
                      aria-describedby="datenschutz-description"
                      {...register("datenschutz", {
                        required: true,
                      })}
                      type="checkbox"
                      /*className="focus:ring-green h-4 w-4 text-green border-gray-300 rounded"*/
                      className={classNames(errors.datenschutz ?
                          "border-red-500 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500" :
                          "focus:ring-green text-green border-gray-300",
                        "h-4 w-4 rounded")}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
                    <p id="comments-description" className="text-gray-500">
                      Ich habe die <Link to={"/datenschutz/"}
                                         className={"text-green underline"}>Datenschutzerklärung</Link> zur Kenntnis genommen.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  className="text-sm text-red-500">{errors.datenschutz && "Bitte der Datenschutzerklärung zustimmen"}
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div id={"thanksection"} className={"hidden"}>
              <div className="font-semibold pt-5 text-gray-500 text-lg text-green-light">
                Vielen Dank!
              </div>
              <div className="mb-4  text-gray-500 text-lg">
                Ihre Anfrage wurde an uns übermittelt.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id={"errorsection"} className={"hidden"}>
              <div className="font-semibold pt-5 text-gray-500 text-lg">
                Oh, Entschuldigung.
              </div>
              <div className="mb-4  text-gray-500 text-lg">
                Es scheint ein Fehler bei der Verarbeitung passiert zu sein.
              </div>
            </div>

            {/*{errors && <div
                className={"text-red-500 pl-2 text-sm mt-2"}>Fehler: {errors}</div>
              }*/}
          </div>
          <div className="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6" id={"buttonsection"}>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
              <button
                type="submit"
                id={`easyform_btn_submit`}
                disabled={isDisabled}
                className="w-40 py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm
              text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-gray-800 bg-green-lighter hover:bg-green-light
              focus:outline-none"
              >
                {butttonText}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>strong text
  )
}
```

And my form submission looks like this:

```html
const submitFormToPowerAutomator = async (body) => {
  const payload = {
    "firstname": body.firstname,
    "lastname": body.lastname,
    "phone": body.phone,
    "email": body.email,
    "fin": body.fin,
  }

  const url = "https://prod-30.germanywestcentral.logic.azure.com:443/...........";
  return fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  })

}
```

And the JSON request looks like this

```html
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstname": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastname": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "phone": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "fin": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-the-current-url-with-javascript)

Comment: Probably the right command but I just don’t know how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the payload like this

```
  const payload = {
    "firstname": body.firstname,
    "lastname": body.lastname,
    "phone": body.phone,
    "email": body.email,
    "fin": body.fin,
    "url": window.location.href
  }
```

This will add the url of the current page to the payload that is being sent in the post request.